# Chrome font color 'clipping'

Tags: css, google-chrome, colors

I have my links change color on hover, but the full text isnt changing and leaving clipped bits the default color making it look buggy.

Is there a way to solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/C8K8z/

```
a{
    font-family:'Oleo Script';
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;

}
a:hover{
    color:#c41313;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: please post some code and a jsfiddle :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C8K8z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the Oleo Script font. It isn't 100% consistent, but some of the characters' font design (the hinting?) can cause the edges to end outside the element's box.

I would recommend using another font that doesn't have this issue, but if you're committed to Oleo, you can add padding to the left and right to work around it.

```
a{
    font-family:'Oleo Script';
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
}
```

Also, your fiddle wasn't importing the font correctly (a problem with jsfiddle I believe), but I was able to get it to work by using the Google Font JavaScript import option instead of linking the css resource.

You can see the font problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/aYxEU/

And the fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/hFgaw/

Comment: Yeah i was already going with the padding quick fix in the hopes that there was something better. I dont understand why its fine in internet explorer, the most useless browser haha.